# Further Sort an already sorted list

Tags: java, android, list

I have a list of `maps` that I have already sorted by one type but now I want to further sort that list

Original sort

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map<String,Object>>(){

  @Override
  public int compare(Map<String, Object> m1,Map<String, Object> m2) {

      return m1.get("type").toString().compareTo(m2.get("type").toString()); //type is a 1 or 0
  }         
});
```

Now what I want to do is keep that order but I want to sort that list further by the persons last name. Am I going to have to split this into 2 lists, one list of type `0` and another with type `1` then just add the lists together?

basically I want to replicate a SQL sort where I would do `type ASC, lastName ASC` and give me a list sorted by type with the types sorted by last name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
int compareType = m1.get("type").toString().compareTo(m2.get("type").toString());
if(compareType != 0) {
   return compareType;
}
return m1.get("name").toString().compareTo(m2.get("name").toString());
```

If you are sorting on many keys this would be cleaner:

```
for(String key : new String[] { "type", "name" }) {
   int compare = m1.get(key).toString().compareTo(m2.get(key).toString());
   if(compare != 0) {
      return compare;
   }
}
return 0;
```